# Sort Date[dd/MM/yyyy] which is in NSString data type inside an array in Objective-C for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I have an NSMutableArray which holds the dates in format dd/MM/yyyy of type NSString.
Now i need to display the sorted array of dates. Please suggest me how to achieve it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. You can use NSMutableArray's `sortUsingFunction` or `sortUsingSelector` etc. methods. Create the sort method or function which takes string parameters (array object's datatype), converts the strings to dates using NSDateFormatter's `dateFromString` method, compares the two dates using NSDate's `compare` method and return the comparison result. For a typical example of the sort function for an array, see [NSArray class reference - sortedArrayUsingFunction](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCHBAHB).
2. Implement any of typical sort algorithms (like quick sort) yourself. In the implementation convert the date to string before you compare two elements.